# Finding XPath expression of a link using link text

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, platform

In [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver), how can I to use an XPath expression for the below HTML using the *link text* ("Add New Button")?

```
<a href="SOME URL">
  <span >
    <i class=""/>
  </span>Add New Button
</a>
```

I tried to inspect the element as below, but all didn’t work.

1. `//a[text()='Add New Button']`
2. `//a[contains(text(),'Add New Button']`
3. `//a/span/i[text()='Add New Button']`
4. `//a/span/i[contains(text(),'Add New Button']`

I know that 3 and 4 won't, but I just tried it.

So for such an HTML DOM, how can I find the link using the link text using XPath?

Comment: Try with //a[contains(., 'Add New Button')]

Comment: 2) Is missing a closing parenthesis isn't it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some of the answers that were already given work, but others don't. And I think the OP would benefit from more explanations.

Your original expression:

```
//a[text()='Add New Button']
```

Does not work because the text node that contains "Add New Button" also has a newline character at the end.

The next one:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Add New Button']
```

Does not work (leaving aside the missing parenthesis), because `text()` returns a *sequence* of nodes and a function like `contains()` will only evaluate the *first* node in the sequence. In this case, the first text node inside `a` only contains whitespace and is *not* the one that contains "Add New Button".

You can validate this claim with:

```
//a[contains(text()[2],'Add New Button')]
```

which will test whether the *second* text node of `a` contains "Add New Button"—and this expression will return the `a` element. But the best solution in this case is:

```
//a[contains(.,'Add New Button')]
```

`.` will evaluate to the so-called "string value" of an element, a concatenation of all its text nodes which will include "Add New Button".

---

A solution with `normalize-space()` is also possible, but it has nested predicates:

```
//a[text()[normalize-space(.) = "Add New Button"]]
```

Comment: In the second method, you missed a parenthesis of `contains`

Comment: @BlackThunder You're right, edited - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

With an XPath expression, you can check if the element contains a certain text with the below statement:

```
//a[contains(., 'Button')]
```

Answer (score 2):

The link text contains unnecessary spaces from the right side of the main text, so you need the following to get rid of them:

```
'//a[normalize-space(.)="Add New Button"]'
```

Comment: This answer returns the correct result, but for the wrong reason. `text()="Add New Button"` evaluates to "false" because there is no such text node. `normalize-space()` will interpret the boolean as a string (identical to the result of: `string(//a/text() ="Add New Button")`) and the whole predicate boils down to: `//a[true]`. You can test this by removing "Add New Button" from the HTML and the `a` element will still be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Add New Button')]
```

or

```
//a/i[contains(text(),'Add New Button')]
```

or

```
//a[@href='SOME URL']/i
```

or using `cssSelector` -

```
a[href='SOME URL']>i
```

Comment: The first two of your suggestions are wrong (they do not return any result), and the other two disregard the fact that "Add New Button" should be used to identify the element.